# How to fit 2 products in the screen when it's in mobile?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I've been stuck on this part, and I've been struggling how can I manage to make it row, I tried to make it flexWrap, but it's going down instead of going its side.

```
   <Box sx={{display: {xs: 'flex'}, 
                     gap: {xs: '0px', md:'20px', 
                     flexWrap: 'wrap', 
                     alignItems: 'center' }}}
                     >
      {products.map((product) => (
        <CardProduct key={product._id}  product={product}/>
      ))}
   </Box>
```

[outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gPY8.png)

this is I want to achieve, the first and second product must be align, and then have a gap between or spacing, then the 3rd product will automatically wrap... I tried to call the

> ***flexWrap:'wrap'***

but it failed. should I just the height ? or is it because the button is too big?

[want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAZM2.png)

This is what it looks like when it only have two products

[two images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHnx7.png)

Comment: The obvious answer is to add whatever material-ui class that changes the `flex-direction` to `row` (from the assumed `column`), or simply remove the class-name that specifies `flex-direction: column`, since `row` is the default.

Comment: Consider `{xs: 'flex'},` just making it ` 'flex',` - or just give it a class which can maintain all the CSS

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [`Grid`](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/):

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
  {products.map((product) => (
    <Grid item xs={6} key={product._id}>
      <CardProduct product={product} />
    </Grid>
  ))}
</Grid>;
```

Answer (score 0):

To make 2 columns you can use [flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) property, flex-basis: 50%; , do remove any padding or margin before.
with flex-basis property you can set any width or get number of columns.

```
<Box sx={{display: {xs: 'flex'}, 
     gap: {xs: '0px', md:'20px', 
     flex-basis: '50%',
     alignItems: 'center' }}}
   >
  {products.map((product) => (
    <CardProduct key={product._id}  product={product}/>
  ))}
```

There is on more property in css that helps us to achieve any number of coumns without using flexbox.

```
.div {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try Grid. Material-UI has a very good and clear example exactly as you want.

[link](https://v4.mui.com/components/grid/#grid)

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
  <Grid item xs={12}>
    <Grid container justifyContent="center" spacing={spacing}>
      {[0, 1, 2].map((value) => (
        <Grid key={value} item>
          <Paper className={classes.paper} />
        </Grid>
      ))}
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```